# D3 x-axis tick format & tick value issues

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am trying to format date-time ticks for the x-axis but i am not able to achieve what i want to.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var z = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");

var data = [{
  data: [
    ["2016-01-28T15:45:26Z", 5.0],
    ["2016-01-30T15:45:26Z", 0.0],
    ["2016-02-01T15:45:26Z", 0.0],
    ["2016-02-03T15:45:26Z", 0.0],
    ["2016-02-05T15:45:26Z", 0.0],
    ["2016-02-07T15:45:26Z", 0.0],
    ["2016-02-09T15:45:26Z", 0.0],
    ["2016-02-11T15:45:26Z", 0],
    ["2016-02-13T15:45:26Z", 0],
    ["2016-02-15T15:45:26Z", 0],
    ["2016-02-17T15:45:26Z", 0],
    ["2016-02-19T15:45:26Z", 0],
    ["2016-02-21T15:45:26Z", 0],
    ["2016-02-23T15:45:26Z", 0],
    ["2016-02-25T15:45:26Z", 0]
  ],
  label: "a"
}]


var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("monotone")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(parseDate.parse(d[0]));
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  });

var ary = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  ary.push(d.data);
});

x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return parseDate.parse(d[0]);
}));

y.domain([
  d3.min(data, function(c) {
    return d3.min(c.data, function(v) {
      return v[1];
    });
  }),
  d3.max(data, function(c) {
    return d3.max(c.data, function(v) {
      return v[1];
    });
  })
]);

function calc(val) {
  var day = Math.floor((new Date() - val) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  if (day === 0) {
    return 'today';
  } else {

    return '-' + day + 'D';
  }
}

xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
  console.log("=========");
  console.log(d);
  console.log("=========");
  return calc(d);
});
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

var series = svg.selectAll(".series")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "series");

series.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.data);
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  });
```

```css
text.inner-circle {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
text.inner-text {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: 'Metric Regular', 'Metric';
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 2;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

When i printing `x.domain()`, i am getting output as `[Thu Jan 28 2016 15:45:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Thu Feb 25 2016 15:45:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)]` which are correct min & max values according to data with correct time.

But when below mentioned snippet of code runs, it doesn't starts passing values from `Fri Jan 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` instead of `Thu Jan 28 2016 15:45:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`-

```
xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
console.log("=========");
console.log(d);
console.log("=========");
return calc(d);
});
```

So when the above snippet runs, it give me these values of `d`: Console Output

```
=========
Fri Jan 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Sun Jan 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Mon Feb 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Wed Feb 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Fri Feb 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Sun Feb 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Tue Feb 09 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Thu Feb 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Sat Feb 13 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Mon Feb 15 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Wed Feb 17 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Fri Feb 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Sun Feb 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Tue Feb 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
=========
Thu Feb 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
=========
```

But i want code to pass date-time values that are mentioned in the input without changing them.

Please help me.

Comment: Not clear on this part of your question: _But when below mentioned snippet of code runs, it doesn't starts passing values from `Fri Jan 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` instead of `Thu Jan 28 2016 15:45:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)-`_ can you explain more on this please?

Comment: @Cyril When i am running the mentioned snippet, it is passing values of `d` as `Fri Jan 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` and then next value it is passing is `Sun Jan 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` and so on. But i want values that is present in the data to be passed not these modified values.

Comment: OK i got what you mean, the `d3.time.scale()` gives a range of +/- 1 day. That's the reason for the anomaly.  If you give `d3.time.linear` you will get the ticks accordingly as shown here http://plnkr.co/edit/m4kJjT3crSiqw5GSY6wx?p=preview

Comment: But where to add this `d3.time.scale()` method? Please can you fix my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard behaviour of `axis` is to use regularly-spaced ticks with nice round values.

Since you know precisely where you want your ticks; then `axis.tickValues([values])` is your friend. Extract the list of date-times from your data and give them to your `xAxis` through this function.

Edit: to get your array of values, the following lines should do the work

```
myTickValues = ary[0].map(function(d){return parseDate.parse(d[0])})
xAxis.tickValues(myTickValues);
```

Comment: True that i can pass the array of values to `tickValues()` method but then my format is getting all screwed up. I want to show values in this format `-27D, -25D, -23D` and so on. Please suggest

Comment: @nikunj2512 Strange, even with custom values your `tickFormat` function (i.e. `calc`) should still be called. When you say your format is screwed up, you mean that you directly get the full timestamp, or that your calc function returns a strange output?

Comment: It is giving full timestamp, if i remove `tickformat` but if i don't remove it then i don't see any change from before.

Comment: check this jsfiddle with your suggested changes -> `https://jsfiddle.net/muwvyLLe/8/`

Comment: @nikunj2512 Okay, it seems I should have used `ary[0]` instead of `data`, see https://jsfiddle.net/946w0rk3/